# What are some of the command-line windows FTP clients available?

Tags: windows, ftp, command-line-interface

I'm trying to publish web applications automatically using command-line but the default Windows FTP client does not support recursive upload/download for instance.

What are my alternatives to the default Windows FTP client?

Comment: "Best" is pretty subjective, you should edit your question to indicate your requirements or metrics for qualifying what *you* consider best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Winscp**](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is a native Microsoft Windows client that has a command line and scripting  interface which supports recursive upload and download. Whether it's the best I wouldn't like to say.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) 4.2.3 exists in [the cygwin repositories](http://www.cygwin.com/mirrors.html). It's a very powerful command-line ftp client, very scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

I note the "ultimate" ftp client is still unmentioned - there is a Windows port for [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/)

Answer (score 0):

http://curl.haxx.se/ <- Curl, does provide ftp among other protocols